# 2D complex array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am new in C++ programing so I need a help about 2D arrays. Is it possible to create complex array from two real array with two for loops?I was trying to do that in my code but...I do not know how to do that.
Thanks for help!
This is my code::

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int const BrGr = 15, BrCv = BrGr + 1, BrSat = 24;
//(BrCv=number of nodes,BrSat=number of hours)

int main()
{
    // Every array must be dynamic array.It is a task.Is this correct way?

    auto *Ipot = new double[BrCv - 1][BrSat];
    auto *cosfi = new double[BrCv - 1][BrSat];
    auto *S_pot = new complex<double>[BrCv - 1][BrSat];
    auto *I_inj = new complex<double>[BrCv - 1][BrSat];
    auto *V_cvo = new complex<double>[BrCv][BrSat];

    ifstream reader("Input.txt");
    if (reader.is_open())
    {
        for (int i = 0;i < BrCv - 1;i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0;j < BrSat;j++)
            {
                reader >> Ipot[i][j];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0;i < BrCv - 1;i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0;j < BrSat;j++)
            {
                reader >> cosfi[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    else cout << "Error!" << endl;
    reader.close();

    // Here i want to create 2D array of complex numbers -  Is this correct way?
    // Also in same proces i want to calculate a value of S_pot in every node for every hour

    for (int i = 0;i < BrCv - 1;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0;j < BrSat;j++)
        {
            S_pot[i][j] = complex<double>(Ipot[i][j]*cosfi[i][j],Ipot[i][j]*sqr(1-pow(cosfi[i][j],2)));
        }
    }
    // Here i give a value for V_cvo in nodes for every single hour

    for (int i = 0;i < BrCv;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0;j < BrSat;j++)
        {
            V_cvo[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }

    // Here i want to calculate a value of I_inj in every node for every hour

    for (int i = 0;i < BrCv - 1;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0;j < BrSat;j++)
        {
            I_inj[i][j] = conj(S_pot[i][j] / V_cvo[i][j]);
        }
    }

    // Here i want to delete all arrays

    delete[] Ipot, cosfi, S_pot, I_inj, V_cvo;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
```

Comment: `new complex<double>BrCv - 1][BrSat];` - you seem to me missing a `[`. And `delete[] Ipot, cosfi` isn't valid either. You need to `delete[]` each of those in separate operations, and may as well `delete [] Spot;` while you're at it.

Comment: I fixed that but..again I hade a problem...with creating Spot.
Is this way a possible or there is some other ways?

Comment: How do you know it isn't working? What result do you want, and what result do you see?

Comment: The long weekend has put my clairvoyance on the hiatus. How about you specify exactly *the* problem you're trying to solve. Before your problem was the code couldn't *compile*.

Comment: Is this the proper way to use a class for working with complex numbers and is this how the for loop creates compleksan number?
 It interests me because I did not until now has never worked in C ++, I've just started learning the language.

Answer (score 4):

Note: I'm using double through out these examples, but you can replace double with any type.

To be honest, you probably don't want to use a 2D array.

Creating a 2D dynamically-sized array in C++ is a multi-stage operation. You can't just

```
double twoDArray [nrRows][nrColumns];
```

or

```
auto twoDArray = new double[nrRows][nrColumns];
```

There are a couple things wrong with this, but the most important is the rows and columns are not a constant, defined at compile time values. Some compilers allow the first, but this cannot be guaranteed. I don't know if any compiler allows the second.

Instead, First you create an array of rows to hold the columns, then you separately create each row of columns. Yuck.

Here's the set up:

```
double * arr[] = new double*[nrRows]; // create rows to point at columns
for (size_t index = 0; index < nrRows; index++)
{
    arr[index] = new double[nrColumns]; // create columns
}
```

And here's clean-up

```
for (size_t index = 0; index < nrRows; index++)
{
    delete[] arr[index]; // delete all columns
}
delete[] arr; // delete rows
```

For your efforts you get crappy [spacial locality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) and the performance hit ([Cache miss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache)) that causes because your many arrays could be anywhere in RAM, and you get crappy memory management issues. One screw-up, one unexpected exception and you have a memory leak.

This next option has better locality because there is one big data array to read from instead of many, but still the same leakage problems.

```
double * arr2[] = new double*[nrRows]; // create rows to point at columns
double holder[] = new double[nrRows* nrColumns]; // create all columns at once
for (size_t index = 0; index < nrRows; index++)
{
    arr[index] = &holder[index * nrColumns]; // attach columns to rows
}
```

and clean up:

```
delete[] arr2;
delete[] holder;
```

In C++, the sane person chooses std::vector over a dynamically-sized array unless given very, ***very*** compelling reason not to. Why has been documented to death all over SO and the Internet at large, and the proof litters the Internet with hijacked computers serving up heaping dollops of spam and other nastiness.

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec(nrRows, std::vector<double>(nrColumns));
```

Usage is exactly what array users are used to:

```
vec[i][j] = somevalue;
```

This has effectively no memory problems, but is back to crappy locality because the vectors could be anywhere.

But...!

There is a better method still: Use a One Dimensional array and wrap it in a simple class to make it look 2D.

```
template <class TYPE>
class TwoDee
{
private:
    size_t mNrRows;
    size_t mNrColumns;
    vector<TYPE> vec;
public:
    TwoDee(size_t nrRows, size_t nrColumns): 
        mNrRows(nrRows), mNrColumns(nrColumns), vec(mNrRows*mNrColumns)
    {

    }
    TYPE & operator()(size_t row, size_t column)
    {
        return vec[row* mNrColumns + column];
    }
    TYPE operator()(size_t row, size_t column) const
    {
        return vec[row* mNrColumns + column];
    }
};
```

This little beastie will do most of what you need a 2D vector to do. You can copy it, you can move it. You can crunch all you want. Jay Leno will make more.

I jumped directly to the templated version because I'm stumped for a good reason to explain class TwoDee twice.

The constructor is simple. You give it the dimensions of the array and it builds a nice, safe 1D vector. No muss, no fuss, and No Zayn required.

The operator() functions take the row and column indices, do a simple bit of arithmetic to turn the indices into a single index and then either return a reference to the indexed value to allow modification or a copy of the indexed value for the constant case.

If you're feeling like you need extra safety, add in range checking.

```
TYPE & operator()(size_t row, size_t column)
{
    if (row < mNrRows && column < mNrColumns)
    {
        return vec[row* mNrColumns + column];
    }
    throw std::out_of_range("Bad indices");
}
```

OK. How does the OP use this?

```
TwoDee<complex<double>> spot(BrCv - 1, BrSat);
```

Created and ready to go. And to load it up:

```
for (int i = 0;i < BrCv - 1;i++)
{
    for (int j = 0;j < BrSat;j++)
    {
        Spot(i,j) = complex<double>(7.8*Ipot(i,j),2.3*cosfi(i,j));
    }
}
```

Comment: For being more `C++` than `C`, I am giving you +1

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I am a beginner.
I'm not sure I fully understand all the code that you wrote.

Comment: To be honest, most of it is trying to explain why you don't want to do what you are doing. I recommend focusing the last half with the TwoDee class, but the easiest, safest way to do what you want is to get rid of the arrays and use [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Creating the vecor is simple: `std::vector<std::vector<complex<double>>> Spot(BrCv - 1, std::vector<complex<double>>(BrSat));` and using it is exactly the same as what you are currently doing.

Comment: I've made changes in the code. This time I wrote specifically what I need to do and how to code.
Since I'm a beginner in C ++ I would ask you to show me the concept of declaration of dynamic 2D arrays that are complex.

Comment: @JohnCorn No. I won't do it. Creating an array of complex is no different than creating any other array. If you haven't been able to figure it out from the various examples already presented by me and others, you need to go back to the books, do more studying, and write a bunch of small programs to help you figure out what you are missing.

Comment: Now your suggestion seems the only way.
Thank you for the effort and help.

Answer (score 3):

Declaring a dynamic 2D array for a premitive type is the same as for `std::complex<T>`.

Jagged array:

```
complex<int> **ary = new complex<int>*[sizeY];
//run loop to initialize
for (int i = 0; i < sizeY; ++i) 
{
    ary[i] = new complex<int>[sizeX];
}
//clean up (you could wrap this in a class and write this in its destructor)
for (int i = 0; i < sizeY; ++i) 
{
    delete[] ary[i];
}
delete[] ary;
//access with
ary[i][j];
//assign index with
ary[i][j] = complex<int>(int,int);
```

It's a little heavier weight than it needs to be, and it allocates more blocks than you need.
Multidimensional arrays only need one block of memory, they don't need one block per row.

Rectangular array:

```
complex<int> *ary = new complex<int>[sizeX * sizeY];
//access with:
ary[y*sizeX + x]
//assign with
ary[y*sizeX+x] = complex<int>(int,int);
//clean up
delete[] ary;
```

Allocating just a single contiguous block is the way to go (less impact on allocator, better locality, etc But you have to sacrifice clean and nice subscripting.

Comment: @JohnCorn That is the way for populating the 2 2d arrays. But you've not written code to populate the `complex` array. See how i populate the `complex` array in my example above.

Comment: I've made changes in the code. This time I wrote specifically what I need to do and how to code. Since I'm a beginner in C ++ I would ask you to show me the concept of declaration of dynamic 2D arrays that are complex